# Error result is not defined while transfer data from express to ejs

Tags: javascript, express, ejs

I create a function in expressjs to query data and export it to ejs file
This is my express file

```
const getHomepage = (req, res) => {
    connection.connect(function (err) {
        if (err) throw err
        console.log("Connected!");
        connection.query(`SELECT * FROM Users`, function (err, results) {
            if (err) throw err;
            console.log(results);
        });
    });
    return res.render('start.ejs', {listUsers: results});
}
```

This is my ejs

```
<%= listUsers %>
```

And this is the error.

```
ReferenceError: results is not defined
at getHomepage (C:\Users\Admin\Documents\Developing-Coding-Programming UoG\program year 2 ae\NodeJS\src\controller\homeControl.js:12:48)
at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\Users\Admin\Documents\Developing-Coding-Programming UoG\program year 2 ae\NodeJS\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
at next (C:\Users\Admin\Documents\Developing-Coding-Programming UoG\program year 2 ae\NodeJS\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:144:13)
at Route.dispatch (C:\Users\Admin\Documents\Developing-Coding-Programming UoG\program year 2 ae\NodeJS\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:114:3)
at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\Users\Admin\Documents\Developing-Coding-Programming UoG\program year 2 ae\NodeJS\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
at C:\Users\Admin\Documents\Developing-Coding-Programming UoG\program year 2 ae\NodeJS\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:284:15
at Function.process_params (C:\Users\Admin\Documents\Developing-Coding-Programming UoG\program year 2 ae\NodeJS\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:346:12)
at next (C:\Users\Admin\Documents\Developing-Coding-Programming UoG\program year 2 ae\NodeJS\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:280:10)
at Function.handle (C:\Users\Admin\Documents\Developing-Coding-Programming UoG\program year 2 ae\NodeJS\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:175:3)
at router (C:\Users\Admin\Documents\Developing-Coding-Programming UoG\program year 2 ae\NodeJS\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:47:12)
```